# C# Interop.Word insert image into paragraph

Tags: c#, office-interop

So with Visual Studio/C# and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

I have this code which places text correctly to the word doc

```
        private void WriteBookLine(string theLine, int al, string font, int fontSize, int fontBold, int spaceAfter)
    {
        paraTop = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        paraTop.Range.Text = theLine;
        if (al == 0)
            paraTop.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
        else if (al == 1)
            paraTop.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;
        paraTop.Range.Font.Name = font;
        paraTop.Range.Font.Size = fontSize;
        paraTop.Range.Font.Bold = fontBold;
        paraTop.Format.SpaceAfter = spaceAfter;
        paraTop.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
    }
```

But when I call this code to place a picture as the next paragraph in the word doc

```
        private void WriteBookImage(int im)
    {
        paraTop = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        if (im == 0)
        {
            doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\fred\source\repos\xxx\wwwroot\images\yyy.png");
        }
        paraTop.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
    }
```

This places the image at the very top of the document on page 1, line 1 instead as the next paragraph, any ideas where I am going wrong please

Cheers

Kev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this first:

```cs
    private void WriteBookImage(int im)
    {
        paraTop = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
        if (im == 0)
        {
            //you should specify the range [where] to add inlineshpae
            //in this case, doc will be the [where] and the last InlineShape in the doc will be the exactly [where]
            //doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\fred\source\repos\xxx\wwwroot\images\yyy.png");
            //in this case, paraTop(the last paragrahp you just added it in before) will be the [where]
            // the [where] argument just like the parameter Range of the object Hyperlinks Bookmark, etc, and Anchor of the object Shape, in their method Add.
            //paraTop.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\fred\source\repos\xxx\wwwroot\images\yyy.png");

            doc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\fred\source\repos\xxx\wwwroot\images\yyy.png", Range:paraTop.Range.Next()); // specify by argument Range, use Next methot to get the new paragraph just be added before.
//In my testing yesterday, I found an error in the official documentation, and have already submitted a correction:
//Returns a **Paragraph** object When the caller is not the last paragraph in a document, that represents a new, blank paragraph added to a document, otherwise, that will be the calling paragraph itself.
//https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/VBA-Docs/pull/1727/commits/ddd0bbe1b29e90a64012dd8d1e9ec9a1a3c86e4f
//https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/office-developer-word-pia-ref-dotnet/pull/22#issuecomment-1637070970
        }
        paraTop.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
        // if you want to insert the new paragraph here then : 
        //paraTop.Range.Next().InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"C:\Users\fred\source\repos\xxx\wwwroot\images\yyy.png");           
    }
```